# Insert unicode data through stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
    @Username NVARCHAR(300),
    @Password NVARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp 
    (
         username NVARCHAR(300),
         pwd NVARCHAR(300)
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (@Username, @Password)

    SELECT * FROM #temp
END
```

When I call the stored procedure like this:

```
Test 'ABC','pass_123'
```

It shows me the correct data.

But when I call the stored procedure like this:

```
TEST 'ABC','系统信息'
```

In passwords field it shows like `????`

I understood its a unicode code so I tried :

```
TEST 'ABC',N'系统信息'
```

And it works.

So my question is how we can add the literal N' while inserting the password in the stored procedure?

Comment: The parameter is passed in SP already converted to varchar. You should convert the parameter to nvarchar before passing in SP. Prefix N is one of the ways to do this. Interpret all string literals as nvarchar by default is impossible (only set the needed collation - but it works for one language).

Comment: How? You write the code that executes the stored procedure correctly. It is that simple. There is no magic here - nothing will automatically compensate for a coding error.

Answer (score -1):

try to execute this command in order to show Chinese in your database

```
alter database <your_db_name> collate Chinese_PRC_CI_AS
```

Comment: I have french,japanese,russian password as well